# Automatic SiteMap Generator for laravel ! i Cant install spatie/laravel from github , i am using laravel 5.4.*?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sitemap, sitemapprovider

i get this error when i try to install `spatie/laravel` from `github`.

> - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.4.36
>
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
>   - spatie/laravel-sitemap 3.3.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.5.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33].
>   - spatie/laravel-sitemap 3.3.1 requires illuminate/support ~5.5.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33].
>   - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
>   - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
>   - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
>   - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
>   - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
>   - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
>   - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.4.36, required as 5.4.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.36].
>   - Installation request for spatie/laravel-sitemap ^3.3 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-sitemap[3.3.0, 3.3.1].

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the stack trace.

```
spatie/laravel-sitemap 3.3.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.5.0
```

You need to either upgrade to Laravel 5.5 or downgrade the spatie package

You'll need version `2.4.0` to work with Laravel 5.4. Add it composer.json as

```
"spatie/laravel-sitemap": "^2.4.0"
```

Next run

```
// if lockfile exists 
composer update 

// no lockfile
composer install
```

Comment: what i did is while installing spatie , i mentioned the version in "2.4.0" . and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For my Laravel Framework 5.4.36 I have used spatie laravel-sitemap 2.4.0 
It working good , without any problem
Just manually add in composer.json require section this line of code

```
 "spatie/laravel-sitemap": "^2.4.0",
```

then via cmd

> composer update